# Release absolutely positioned child from relative positioned parent

Tags: jquery, css

This is the situation...

HTML:

```
   <div id="cw">
        <div id="c"></div>        
   </div>
   <a href="#">click me</a>
```

CSS:

```
#cw {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 100px 200px 0 200px;     
    padding: 10px;
}

#c {
    background: blue;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;    
}
```

-> http://jsfiddle.net/F6FF2/4/

Now, what I'm trying to achieve is this. If the "click me" link is clicked, the inner container `#c` is supposed to expand to the full extent of the window from the location it has been rendered on the page.

I figured that this can only be achieved by assigning `position: absolute` to the element. But then I run into the problem that its parent is positioned relative.

So what I have come up with so far is cloning `#c`, removing it from the DOM and appending the clone to the `body` before animating its expansion delivers the desired result. The problem is, however, if `#c` contains for example a Google Map, the map has to be reinstantiated after the cloning event (rather than just refreshing the tiles).

Apart from the fact that this solution seems a rather messy. There must be a better, cleaner solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: For questions related to optimising working code, please use http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is not so much about optimising working code. The code is merely there to demonstrate what I'm after. I'd be more curious to see whether it can be done by other means (e.g. CSS mainly).

Comment: This is not a codereview question IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the contents(the map) here:

```
c.text(c_width+" > "+c_height+" > "+c_left+" > "+c_top);
```

Don't overwrite the contents, also don't use a clone(move the original ), trigger the resize-event instead when finising the animation:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6FF2/10/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **moving** the div to the body element instead of cloning it?

```
$("body").append($("#c"))
```

You can then move it back when you're done:

```
$("#cw").append($("#c"))
```